# How to display my cells textlabel name in my detailtextlabel in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have created 2 controllers both have tableview in it.
when i pop from my second controller to my first controller the cell that i have selected in my second controller to pop to my first controller,the text of that cell should get displayed in the detailtextlabel of my first controller.Can anybody help me in solving this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Abishek if i am clearly understanding your problem you want to take the text that u had selected from your secondView Controller to your `detailtextLabel` of your firstView controller.....For this i request you to declare a variable in your `AppDelegate` class

eg:-Let suppose a variable is of `NSString` type i.e country in the AppDelegate class

In your secondView Controller where you are selecting the text.....give it to

```
appDelegate.country(appDelegate is a object of AppDelegate class)
```

Now when you pop to firstView controller ...in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` give `detailtextLabel.text = appDelegate.country` you will get the text and choose tableViewtype:`UITableViewCellStyleValue2` and in its.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
```

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: actually the problem is that i want to the code to be called in a method - (void)reactionChosen:(NSString *)inReaction
{
 }which is in the first controller and i am passing this method as a selector to the second controller.How is it possible

Comment: @Abhishek u can call he method of the fistview in the secondView through selector but u cannot write through that  because when u get back to your firstView again its IB will again created....so i suggest u to do it through appdelegate as i had given u above

Comment: Hi sudhanshu,i have tried u r code in my first controller and second controller but it is not working can u please tell me  where to write the code detailtextLabel.text = appDelegate.country in the first controller or second controller and in which method of tableview

Comment: as u told i have added this code in the cellForRowIndexPath of first controller detailtextLabel.text = appDelegate.country but it is giving me error that appDelegate undeclared.Please help me

Comment: appDelegate is the object of AppDelegate class ....i think u r not reading my code sciencerily....like this AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; n follow link..http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/03/uitableview-drill-down-table-view.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cells to display new data, i.e. the textLabel name, you'll have to reload your UITableView.

Assuming you've done all the coding necessary to pass the textLabel name back to the first controller and have this name displayed in a cell, you just need to run:

```
[yourTableView reloadData];
```

and all the cells will be refreshed.

Comment: i have not done the code to pass textLabel name back to first controller and i need the code and i want this code to be called in a function .How is this possible.